# Logback configuration error when running Spring boot on linux vm - windows vm is ok

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have a spring boot app hosted on an azure app service which starts fine on a windows vm but on linux vm I get this logback error (scroll down for full stacktrace):

```
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995698 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995738 ERROR in c******@3:104 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
```

Using:
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.7.RELEASE
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3

I'm just putting this out there, in case anyone has seen this before. Next steps for me would be to either set-up remote debugger to azure or set-up a local linux vm to test.

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="instrumentationKey" source="appinsights.instrumentationkey"/>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener"/>

    <springProfile name="logging-azure">
        <appender name="aiAppender" class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
            <instrumentationKey>${instrumentationKey}</instrumentationKey>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>
    </springProfile>

    <!-- Initial Parent Folder -->
    <variable name="logfilePath" value="br-proposition-logs"/>

    <include resource="standard-logback-config.xml"/>

    <springProfile name="logging-local">
        <root level="ERROR">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
            <appender-ref ref="LOG-FILE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="logging-azure">
        <root level="ERROR">
            <appender-ref ref="aiAppender"/>
            <appender-ref ref="LOG-FILE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

and standard-logback-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<included>

    <variable name="fileName" value="br-proposition"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{proposition.requestId}] %-5level %logger %marker  %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOG-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logfilePath}/${fileName}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="com.lv.gi.traps.common.logging.TrapsSizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${logfilePath}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/${fileName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [${HOSTNAME}:%X{proposition.requestId}] %-5level %logger %marker  %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

</included>
```

Full stacktrace:

2022-08-09T21:04:41.0994993 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995272 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.099543  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995473 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995512 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995549 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995588 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995625 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995661 at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995698 **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:**
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995738 **ERROR in c******@3:104 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]**
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995776 ERROR in c******@6:41 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995815 ERROR in c******@7:115 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995854 ERROR in c******@8:33 - no applicable action for [instrumentationKey], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][instrumentationKey]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995894 ERROR in c******@9:75 - no applicable action for [filter], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][filter]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995933 ERROR in c******@10:24 - no applicable action for [level], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][filter][level]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0995971 ERROR in c******@20:41 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996017 ERROR in c******@21:29 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996057 ERROR in c******@22:41 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996095 ERROR in c******@23:43 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996135 ERROR in c******@27:41 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996174 ERROR in c******@28:29 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.099624  ERROR in c******@29:45 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996281 ERROR in c******@30:43 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996321 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996359 at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996397 at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996434 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996471 at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:306)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996509 at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996547 at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996589 at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996628 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996666 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996705 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996742 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.099678  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996818 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996856 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996897 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996934 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0996971 at com.lv.gi.propositionengine.PropositionEngineInitializer.initialise(PropositionEngineInitializer.java:20)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0997009 at com.lv.gi.br.propositionengine.AppPropositionEngineApplication.main(AppPropositionEngineApplication.java:28)
2022-08-09T21:04:41.0997074 ... 8 more

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed by renaming logback.xml to logback-spring.xml I’m not able to explain why this was only necessary when the jar ran on Linux but not on windows. It works now on both OS’s.

The logback-spring.xml name is recommended by Spring in the spring boot documentation ensuring spring beans required by logback are initialised in time.